# Save users logging time in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, session-cookies

How can I store total users logged time?
We can save the time when users logging in, but the user closes the window how can we store logging out time.

Please guide me through this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the things that you have tried.

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing